# Transferring Clash of Clans from Android to Amazon Fire Tablet

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am trying to get my Clash of Clans account from Android to my Amazon Fire tablet. I have downloaded the Clash of Clans' apk but it will not allow me to sign in. Is there a way I can get Google Play Store to work on my tablet?

Comment: Give more detail, like what is happening when you open Clash of Clans, why it is not letting you log in. Sometimes in Arquade, people appreciate it when you pinpoint the problem rather than just dumping the issue at us.

Answer (score 0):

Just from a quick google around there, it seems to be possible to install the play store on your device. Search for something along the lines of "google play store amazon fire" and you'll get a few results detailing how to do it fully. Essentially it boils down to installing the following via the "install from unknown sources" in this order:

- Google Services Framework
- Google Play Services
- Google Account Manager
- Google Play Store

Once you've gotten the play store working, you can then download apps from it onto your tablet. Since play store app saves are linked to your google account, my best guess would be that you'd need to first get to this stage, sign in to your google account, download the app from the official source, and then see if you can sign in to your game account from there.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that you can install Google Play on a Kindle Fire and connect it to Clash of Clans, as I have finally finish doing it.
Note, however, that as new updates come, the Fire could get updates that ruin this side-load.

I used this: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-get-google-play-on-a-kindle-fire-and-install-any-1790706649

Windows and the Fire were resistant to it working every step of the way and it took four days and three rage quits before I finally got it installed.
Windows wanted to use the driver it felt like using and refused to acknowledge the one I downloaded until I used the "I have the disk" option of the driver install. The 5th Gen Super Tool also had issues recognizing the device existed and failed out many times trying to run it.